# Error en la conversión de string to float

Tags: python, python-3.7

Estoy recibiendo el siguiente error utilizando el módulo folium:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

El código es el siguiente:

```
if c == 'x':
    ip_ = l[:lon_count]
    x = len(ip_)
else:
    lon_count = lon_count + 1
if c == 'y':
    lat = l[lat_count+1:].strip()
    y = len(lat)
    lon = l[x+1:-y-2].strip()
    print(lat,lon)
    folium.Marker(location=[f"{float(lon)}",f"{float(lat)}"],popup=ip_).add_to(map_)
else:
    lat_count = lat_count + 1
```

Obtengo bien las cordenadas pero posteriormente, salta el error al pasar los valores por

> folium.Marker(location=[f"{float(lon)}",f"{float(lat)}"],popup=ip_).add_to(map_)

El output de LAT, LON:

> 42.0432 -31303

2ª parte:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, revisa lo que está impreso justo antes del error, que mostraría lo que imprime tu linea `print(lat,lon)` es probable que algún caracter no sea numérico o punto o que sea un `string` vacío.

Comment: El valor devuelto tiene un signo "-".

Comment: Sin un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) donde podamos reproducir el problema es muy difícil que adivinemos lo que pasa. Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega un ejemplo mínimo y completo que podamos copiar y pegar con el que podamos reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Acabo de poner un Output. Esos valores posteriormente deben ser convertidos a float.

Comment: El valor de `lon` es sospechoso. No es una longitud válida (que ha de estar entre -180 y 180). Haz un `print(repr(lat), repr(lon))` y dinos qué sale.

Comment: `'-3.7026' <built-in function len>
'' <built-in function len>`

Último mensaje de error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Comment: ¿Qué significa tu último comentario? ¿Es la salida de `print(repr(lat), repr(lon))`? De ser así veo cuatro cosas señalables: 1) -3.7026 no coincide con ninguno de los números que mostrabas en la pregunta (42.0432 -31303). 2) Parece que '-3.7026` sería un valor apropiado para la longitud, no para la latitud. 3) Vemos una cadena vacía `''` que sería entonces el valor de `lon` y que explica el error que te da más adelante. y 4) ¿qué son esos `<built-in function len>` que salen? No tienen sentido a menos que hubieras tratado de imprimir `len`.

Comment: Bueno, he actualizado el código, el resultado lo he añadido en dos imágenes posteriores.

Comment: No sólo has añadido `repr()` en el `print()` (que era lo que te había pedido que hicieras), sino también en el parámetro `location=`. Ahí está mal, pues `repr()` te devuelve una cadena que contiene a su vez comillas dentro. Al margen de eso, el resultado mostrado por el `print()` muestra dos cadenas normales, ninguna de ellas vacía. Con esos valores de `lat` y `lon` no deberían producirse ya errores. Además, no son los valores que tú decías que te salían al imprimir (ni lo que muestras en la pregunta, ni lo que mostraste después en un comentario). Así que yo ya no sé en qué caso estamos...

Answer (score 0):

Mirando la foto del error vemos

[image: Error]

que lat y lon contienen **cadenas**.

El método `repr()` genera una **representación textual** del objeto en cuestión. La idea es que si pones ese resultado de vuelta en el código fuente, podrás regenerar el objeto en cuestión.

Como lat y lon son cadenas, la `repr()` correspondiente los muestra con comillas:

```
a = '10'
print("repr(a) = ", repr(a)) # => '10'
print("a = ", a)             # => 10
```

Entonces, cuando llamas a `float(repr(a))` es lo mismo que `float("'10'")`: hay unas comillas simples como parte de la cadena.

**Solución**

Elimina el uso de `repr()`. Convierte lon a lat de inmediato y elimina el resto de las conversiones:

```
lat = float(l[lat_count + 1:].strip())
y = len(lat)
lon = float(l[x + 1:-y - 2].strip())

print(lat, lon)
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar el error es el siguiente: TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: Si mi respuesta arreglo el problema de pregunta, por favor aceptala. Si tienes un problema posterior, puedes hacer una nueva pregunta.